# Still no output from redirection in a cron job

Tags: bash, cron, io-redirection, aide

Every answer to the question of why a cron job results in a zero-length file comes down to using classic output redirection. That still doesn't help, here.

```
# cat /etc/cron.d/aide
SHELL=/bin/bash
48 22 * * * root /usr/sbin/aide --check >/var/log/dailys/aide-$( date +\%Y\%m\%d ).out 2>&1
```

I will only get a zero-length file. If I pull that command out and run it at the bash prompt (dropping the backslashes), I get a filled file.

### UPDATE 1

[@rudimeier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28765/rudimeier) suggested using strace to track my file descriptors. That failed, but in interesting ways.

```
# cat /etc/cron.d/aide
SHELL=/bin/bash
21 13 * * * root strace /usr/sbin/aide --check >/var/log/dailys/aide-$( date +\%Y\%m\%d ).out 2>/var/log/dailys/strace.out
```

The job ran, aide ran without output, and strace showed me that file descriptor assignments started with 3. The only reference to `/var/log/dailys` was when aide checked the permissions and contents of the files in the directory. So, I tried something else: let's kick off the cron job, and look at the various process file descriptors. I wound up having to be a little fast to get this all done, and having [this trick](https://superuser.com/questions/401066/find-what-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-a-pipe) in my pocket gave me more clues for follow up.

```
# ps -ef | grep aide
root 27794 27792 <stuff> /bin/bash -c /usr/sbin/aide --check > /var/log/dailys/aide-$( date +%Y%m%d ).out 2>&1
root 27795 27794 <stuff> /usr/sbin/aide --check

# ls -l /proc/27794/fd
lr-x------. <stuff> 0 -> pipe:[14123645]
l-wx------. <stuff> 1 -> pipe:[14123646]
l-wx------. <stuff> 2 -> pipe:[14123646]

# ls -l /proc/27795/fd
lr-x------. <stuff> 0 -> pipe:[14123645]
lrwx------. <stuff> 1 -> /null
lrwx------. <stuff> 2 -> /null
<stuff>

# ls -l /proc/27792/fd
lrwx------. <stuff> 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------. <stuff> 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------. <stuff> 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------. <stuff> 5 -> anon_inode:inotify
lr-x------. <stuff> 6 -> pipe:[14123646]

# ps -ef | grep 27792
root 27792  3850 <stuff> CROND
<stuff>

# ps -ef | grep 3850
root  3850     1 <stuff> crond
<stuff>
```

So, the STDOUT and STDERR of of the aide process is getting directed to `/null`, the parent `bash` shell is writing to *its* parent. That top process, `CROND`, has no writable FDs. And, I don't see which process might have created `/var/log/dailys/aide-20170803.out` as an empty file to begin with. Curiouser and curiouser...

### UPDATE 2

This all started with [DISA STIG RHEL-07-020030](http://rhel7stig.readthedocs.io/en/latest/medium.html#v-71973-a-file-integrity-tool-must-verify-the-baseline-operating-system-configuration-at-least-weekly-rhel-07-020030), which has `/usr/sbin/aide --check 2>&1 | /bin/mail ...` I'd already tested this and know it works. Why piping and not output redirection?

I went back to the pipe-to-mail version and scanned PIDs and FDs. With the bash pipe arrangement, `aide` actually populates FD 1 and FD2 through the pipe, instead of back to its parent. So, let's play a little...

```
# cat /etc/cron.d/aide
SHELL=/bin/bash
41 14 * * * root /usr/sbin/aide --check | tee /var/log/dailys/aide-$( date +%\Y\%m\%d ).out 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

And that works... I have a weak feeling that `aide` has code that blocks output redirection aside from through a pipe. I'll write the solution when my 24 hours are up.

Comment: I guess there is an error because different cron environment, no terminal etc. I would try to run in with `strace`:  `strace /usr/sbin/aide --check ...`

Comment: FYI - On CentOS 6.9 (32-bit) it works as you originally attempted. Aide v0.14 from the CentOS base repo.

Comment: @Deathgrip - That's weird. My tests are on 64-bit Oracle Linux 6.9 with SELinux enforcing, and aide 0.14. (*sigh* I love computers...)

Answer (score 0):

You are using selinux. If you "setenforce 0" and then let cron run, you will get the output you expect. At the root shell, your selinux context is:

```
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

But when running from Cron, your selinux context starts as:

```
system_u:system_r:system_cronjob_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

`|` to another command works, so you could have also done `| cat > file`

aide then does its own thing with selinux which causes redirection to fail.